# Issue with Running Angular 7 Projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sass, node-sass

After installation of Node.js (10.x & 11.X) versions while running the angular projects `(ng serve -0)` I get the following error message.

> ERROR in ./src/styles.scss
>   (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/ang
>   ular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embe
>   dded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>   Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>       at Object.sassLoader (E:\Projects\my-app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader .js:46:72) i
>   ?wdm?: Failed to compile.

I have gone through a lot of stack overflow questions and angular forum but none of the solutions provided are working for me.

I have tried the following commands :

```
npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass

npm rebuild node-sass --force

npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular

ng update @angular/cli
```

I also tried updating the npm as well with the command : `npm install -g npm@latest`

I have gone through the question : [ERROR in Cannot find module 'node-sass'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147896/error-in-cannot-find-module-node-sass)

But none of the code helps. I tried reinstalling node with different versions but still the same error is being thrown.

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR18I.jpg

**Edit 1**
Please take a look at this [github thread](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12746)

I tried changing the sass in the angular.json file as mentioned in the thread but still the issue persists.

**Edit 2**
I have updated the images in the [imagur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR18I.jpg) The first image shows a response from CLI after successful creation of an angular project. The rest of the four images display the console details of the system having issue in running Angular 7.

I am also adding the pastebin for the aforementioned :

1. [Without Issue](https://pastebin.com/jQ8Wu6jR)
2. [System with Issue](https://pastebin.com/mBjHiUa9)

**Edit 3**

The Angular version details is provided below
[image: <code>ng version</code>]

Comment: did you try `npm rebuild node-sass --force` ?

Comment: Check below solution that solved mine problem. [Solved sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54463979/angular-7-cli-generated-project-throws-error-in-multi-src-styles-sass)

Comment: @MustaphaLarhrouch : yes I have tried that as well! but not working for me.

Comment: @MukeshFulwariya : where should I add it? under the architect object or under the schematics object? I replaced it in both the objects still it doesn't help. Please take a look at : https://imgur.com/a/1iKNcw0

Comment: You need to update your angular cli as well with latest support of node js.  Please try to install angular cli latest version first and then try to serve it.

Comment: @MohitSaxena : already tried that as well! It is reported as bug in the github angular project as Mukesh has pointed out in the comment

Comment: FYI - Angular 7 does not support Node 11 https://v7.angular.io/guide/quickstart . Are you sure you tried using Node 10?